# rails statistic visualizer with method or visualize a different view WEEK/MONTH/YEAR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, statistics, postgresql-9.3

:-) before ask something I prefer to say sorry for may bad english and sorry because I'm a junior developer of rails, in last 3 days I've tried to visualize some statistics in rails but I found a lot of problem somebody can help me ? I leave my DB struct if someone have some good idea

THIS IS WHAT I TRY TO DO: I've tried to visualize some data in a table for know how many event I've all day, and visualize: TOTAL PRICE, TOTAL_EVENT, TOTAL_PAX every day, if you see the DB table you can see I use a date range for every Event, and there I become to get MAD ! in the DB every event is save like this

[image]

AND this is what I want visualize

[image]

for made that I need to use a model because I've 3 view... week / month / year and I think is better use one Method ? right ?

some good idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know if I got what you're trying to do, but I'll explain from what I got.

I'm using a `Hash` to hold the data but you'll probably be using your model.

```
data = [{ id: 1, price: 2, pax: 2, event_room_numer: 1, start_date: "10-10-2015".to_date, end_date: "12-10-2015".to_date }, { id: 2, price: 3, pax: 12, event_room_numer: 3, start_date: "08-10-2015".to_date, end_date: "16-10-2015".to_date }, { id: 1, price: 2, pax: 20, event_room_numer: 3, start_date: "12-10-2015".to_date, end_date: "16-10-2015".to_date }]
```

In the following code I'm creating a `Hash` that will hold the events for a specific day.

```
events_on_day = {}
data.each do |dado|
  (dado[:start_date]..dado[:end_date]).each do |date|
    events_on_day[date] ||= []
    events_on_day[date] << dado
  end
end
```

Then we sort the `Hash` based on the days (the keys).

```
sorted_events_on_day = events_on_day.sort.to_h
```

And finally we get our statistics.

```
statistics = sorted_events_on_day.map do |date, events|
  total_price, total_pax = 0, 0
  total_event = events.count # count the events on the day
  events.each do |event|
    total_price += event[:price] # sum price for the day
    total_pax += event[:pax] # sum pax for the day
  end

  [date, total_event, total_price, total_pax]
end
```

In the `statistics` array we'll have the data for each day. Something like this (for the `data` input):

```
data         total_event   total_price   total_pax
2015-10-08   1             3             12
2015-10-09   1             3             12
2015-10-10   2             5             14
2015-10-11   2             5             14
2015-10-12   3             7             34
2015-10-13   2             5             32
2015-10-14   2             5             32
2015-10-15   2             5             32
2015-10-16   2             5             32
```